# Put textView on an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

In an android app I return from the android camera a bitmap which is set to an `ImageView` something like:

```
   bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                       .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                       image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Further more I wanna put a TextView on this image and after that save it to a website.Someone as an answer to another question on this topic suggested to do this in my xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scaleType="center"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:text="Golden Gate" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Well the problem with this is that the textView won't be there when I save the image and upload it to a website!!!!I assume that this is just for the phone's screen.
Anyway, if someone could help me with this I would appreciate it.Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have access to the Bitmap, you can use the Canvas with that bitmap and draw stuf directly on it:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(theBitMap);
```

After that you can draw the text on to the bitmap with the various canvas methods.
e.g.

```
c.drawText("My Text", xCoord, yCoord, paintObj);
```

See the [Canvas API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) for more information.

Comment: Paint p = new Paint();

just a Paint object you create, on which you can set various flags, e.g. anti aliasing, colors, etc.